# Boolean program returns false, even when it should be true. Simple program

Tags: c++, boolean

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  /*declaring boolean that states if player's health is less than one 
  they are dead/true  */
  int playerHealth = 10;
  bool isPlayerDead=playerHealth < 1;

  //kills player 
  playerHealth = playerHealth - 10;

  //if statement to prove that player died.
  if(isPlayerDead){
      cout << "You died" << endl;
      cout << isPlayerDead << endl;
      cout << playerHealth << endl;
  }
  else{
      cout << "You are alive" << endl;
      cout << isPlayerDead << endl;
      cout << playerHealth << endl;

  }

     return 0;
}
```

If the player takes 10 damage, and their health is now at 0 then their health is less than 1. Wouldn't that make the Boolean true and why is is not?

Comment: What exactly gave you the idea that `isPlayerDead` could be anything other than `false`, forever and in perpetuity??? I'm pretty sure that 10 will never be less than 1 at least until this universe collapses back into one giant black hole. The fact that the shown code changes `playerHealth` to a negative value is something that nobody really cares about, any more, since the value of `isPlayerDead` has already been set. C++ simply does not work the way you think it works.

Answer (score 3):

You've initialized `isPlayerDead` to `false` when you create it.

You then modify `playerHealth` so that the player is dead--but you don't update `isPlayerDead` afterwards, so it still contains false.

If you want it up update every time you use it, consider using a function instead:

```
bool isPlayerDead() { return playerHealth < 1; }

int main() { 
    // ...
    if (isPlayerDead())
        //...
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was something wrong fundamentally, I just couldn't determine it. Just learned booleans today :)